# Receiving 401 Unauthorized WebHook callback channel error with Google Object Change Notification

Tags: python, nginx, google-cloud-storage, google-compute-engine, webhooks

I have been googling this issue for 2 days straight now...

I am trying to establish a bucket change notification through Google's Object Change Notification. All the steps in https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/object-change-notification (and more) have been taken:

- Service Account is made with full access
- Domain is verified
- Has a trusted SSL cert
- Can `curl -X POST` to the server no problem from external machines
- Running `gsutil ls gs://some-bucket` shows all objects in the bucket, so gsutil credentials seem to be fine

But when I try and run `gsutil notification watchbucket https://example.com gs://some-bucket`, the `401 Unauthorized WebHook callback channel`is returned. What could be the issue?

The difference between the link above and my attempt is that the tutorial uses a Google App Engine instance and I am doing this on Google Compute Engine with NGINX. Don't know if I'm missing a key setting or if it's an undocumented limitation.

Thanks for any assistance.

Comment: When you say "Service Account is made with full access", does this service account (and the App Engine account) have OWNER on the ACL for gs://some-bucket ?

Comment: Could you share the output of ``gcloud auth list``?

Comment: Did you whitelist your domain https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/object-change-notification#_Authorize_Endpoint ?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like it might be a symptom of the incident detailed at https://status.cloud.google.com/incident/appengine/15025 -- the timing seems to coincide. The incident in question is now closed (the defect on our side fixed), so please just try again -- if the problem persists, then incident 15025 has nothing to do with it (in which case I apologize for bringing it up!) -- please let us know!

Answer (score 1):

Looks like my boto config file was active which was throwing off credentials. When I disabled this, everything worked smoothly.